# Implement timer in shared code in Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile

Tags: kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm trying to implement a timer function in the shared code of a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile project. The timer shall run for n seconds, and every second it shall call back to update the UI. Moreover, a button in the UI can cancel the timer. This inevitably means I have to start a new thread of some sort, and my question is which mechanism is the appropriate one to use - workers, coroutines or something else?

I have tried using a coroutine with the following code but run into InvalidMutabilityException on iOS:

```
class Timer(val updateInterface: (Int) -> Unit) {
    private var timer: Job? = null

    fun start(seconds: Int) {
        timer = CoroutineScope(EmptyCoroutineContext).launch {
            repeat(seconds) {
                updateInterface(it)
                delay(1000)
            }
            updateInterface(seconds)
        }
    }

    fun stop() {
        timer?.cancel()
    }
}
```

I do know about the moko-time library, but I feel this should be possible without taking on dependencies, and I would like to learn how.

Comment: What is throwing InvalidMutabilityException?

Comment: The iOS app throws InvalidMutabilityException when calling start(), more specifically when the timer property is assigned the return value from launch(). The entire object (that contains the timer property) is frozen, but I'm not sure why - I'm all new to concurrency in Kotlin/native. Could it be because the callback updateInterface is a property of the same object?

Comment: I have just updated the code to make the updateInterface declaration more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspect in the comment, `updateInterface` is a property of the containing class, so capturing a reference to that in the lambda will freeze the parent as well. This is probably the most common and confusing way to freeze your class.

I'd try something like this:

```kotlin
class Timer(val updateInterface: (Int) -> Unit) {
    private var timer: Job? = null

    init {
        ensureNeverFrozen()
    }

    fun start(seconds: Int) {
        val callback = updateInterface
        timer = CoroutineScope(EmptyCoroutineContext).launch {
            repeat(seconds) {
                callback(it)
                delay(1000)
            }
            callback(seconds)
        }
    }

    fun stop() {
        timer?.cancel()
    }
}
```

It's a little verbose, but make a local val for the callback before capturing it in the lambda.

Also, adding `ensureNeverFrozen()` will give you a stack trace to the point where the class is frozen rather than later in the call.

For more detail, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxQ6e1VeH4M&t=1429s and a somewhat simplified blog post series: https://dev.to/touchlab/practical-kotlin-native-concurrency-ac7

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't help. I added ensureNeverFrozen(), and it turns out the object is frozen already when launching the coroutine. I tried changing to GlobalScope but no difference. Does launching a coroutine automatically capture anything in the enclosing object? If yes, is this a reason to use another mechanism than coroutines for the timer thread?

Comment: No, not automatically, unless you capture something. It has nothing directly to do with coroutines as much as the lambda param to launch cannot capture anything from the outside class. When you say "he object is frozen already when launching the coroutine", if you're able to call `start` on the method, and it fails when you launch the coroutine, if you have `ensureNeverFrozen`, that means the coroutine call is freezing it.

Comment: It turns out that the problem in my case lies in the callback function, which both reads and updates states of other objects that holds a reference to the timer. After many failed attempts to resolve the problem, I have resorted to running the timer in the app layer and calling into the shared code on the main thread to avoid any freezing. It's not neat, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing in one of the tasks, using the extension function for coroutine scope:

```
fun CoroutineScope.Ticker(
    tickInMillis: Long,
    onTick: () -> Unit
) {
    this.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        while (true) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { onTick() }
            delay(tickInMillis)
        }
    }
}
```

First implement dispatchers for both platforms, and next call this on a suitable scope.